# How reliable is FCM upstream message delivery?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

The documentation for [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) upstream messages (messages from the device to the server) describes how messages are queued for delivery if the device is offline.

[Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream):

> In cases where the device is offline or the FCM service is unavailable to forward upstream messages to your server, Android client app instances can accumulate a maximum of 20 pending messages.

[iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/upstream):

> The FCM client library caches the message on the client app and sends it when the client has an active server connection.

But what about if the app is closed before the message can be delivered? Does Firebase attempt to use any sort of background service to deliver such messages once the connection is restored? Or are they queued until the app is next opened, or are they discarded entirely?

Edit: in my experiments, there at least is a persistent queue that saves messages across app restarts. But I'm still not sure (on each operating system) what circumstances cause the Firebase messaging service to be running or not, especially when the app is backgrounded.

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS part that you mentioned, it explicitly states that:

> The FCM client library **caches** the message on the client app and sends it when the client has an active server connection.

With that said, I think it is also the same case for Android. So long as the cache isn't cleared for the client app, it should be safe to say that the data is still there. However, it is also good to keep in mind what was mentioned in this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/51041/158980) by @DanHulme:

> **Cached background processes**
>
> Don't forget that Android keeps background processes in memory even when they've stopped running, unless/until another process needs to use that memory. If the app is 'stopped', it's not using any resources, not even if Android is keeping it in memory.

So I think it would be best for you to implement a checker in your client app, whether or not the upstream message was sent successfully, and to re-send it on a later time (*when the connection is already available*) if not.

Comment: The documentation you've quoted mentions a cache, but it doesn't say whether the cache is persistent. That said, in my experiments it has proven to be. What I remain curious about is under what circumstances will the Firebase messaging service actually be alive and attempting to send messages. (Also, unrelated correction about TTL: when the TTL is not included, it defaults to 0, which means the message is either instantly sent or discarded.)

Comment: @ArthurDenture I guess with that said, the question should be more on Android's (or iOS depending on the device) cache persistence and not with the FCM upstream message delivery. For the TTL, pretty sure it says [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options) that the *The default timeout is four weeks, unless the `time_to_live` flag is set*.

Comment: That link describes downstream messages. For upstream messages, [the default ttl value is 0](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Builder.html#setTtl(int)).

Comment: @ArthurDenture Definitely a mistake about upstream TTL on my side. Thanks for pointing that out. :) With that though, I think the question still lies on the cache persistence of the devices (which can vary on Android, I think, depending on the device OS and model).